# Help Creating an Interface

Tags: c#

I'm starting to see the value of Interfaces vs. lets say an Abstract class.

Currently I'm working on a PayPal Wrapper project.  We'll also be probably doing a Google Payments, BillMeLater, and Amazon wrapper.  I've been asked to identify some commonalities (methods, properties, whatever) that we could use across the board, in most any Web Service SOAP Wsdl Wrapper project for any web services we do.

So as I was coding out my PayPal wrappers, I created a new class to hold Errors received back from any PayPal response:

```
public class ApiError
{

    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Disallow default instantiation.
    /// </summary>
    private ApiError()
    {
    }

    internal ApiError(ErrorType error)
    {
        if(error.ErrorCode != null)
        {
            this._errorCode = error.ErrorCode;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region member variables

    private string _errorCode = string.Empty;
    private string _erorMessage = string.Empty;

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public string ErrorCode
    {
        get { return _errorCode; }
        set { _errorCode = value; }
    }

    public string ErrorMessage
    {
        get { return _errorMessage; }
        set { _errorMessage = value; }
    }

    #endregion

}
```

Anyway, I said hey, these ErrorMessage and ErrorCode properties are most likely going to be in every third party API.  So why not create an Interface in a new project called [MyCompany].WebServices.Common and in that interface add those 2 properties.  Then any class wrapper that I create that has functionality to make API proxy calls can implement this interface and then I know any of those kinds of wrapper classes in any of our web service projects will be guaranteed to have these kind of properties in them that will be impolemented and filled with any errors that come back from an API response.

And if they do, then that's great because I can then start to create some helper methods that we can use across the board if I can somehow take in a generic response object and fill the array of errors and set the property.

Anyway, my problem is, I'm new to interfaces a litte.  So the error array property from above for example is of a custom type.

Well if I create interface in a seperate physical project, I can't use that custom type because it doesn't exist..it only exists so far in my PayPal wrapper project.

So then when stubbing this interface out, how would I handle this?

```
namespace [MyCompany].WebServices.Common
{
    interface IRequest
    {

        public ApiError Type { get; set; } //whoops, that's a custom type that this project does not know about (ApiError)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every Problem in Software can be Solved with Another Layer of Indirection!!! Just add another interface called IAPIError that you implement for each pay service error type.

```
interface IRequest
{
   public IApiError Type { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: I don't get it.  So how does IApiError know about my ApiError concrete type?

Comment: It's the other way around. The concrete ApiError class implements IApiError. Whatever class that implements IRequest will know what kind of APIError objects it suppose to return and does so.

Comment: Ah I see.  So I'll have an ApiResponse class in whatever project that implements IRequest.  Since it implemented IRequest it also has to implement IApiError and therefore my ApiResponse class is required to have whatever properties in IApiError?

Comment: Why can't I just have an ApiError custom class that implements straight up IApiError?  Why the nest?

Comment: well that's cool but I"d want an array since an API Response could return serveral errors, not just one.

Comment: So just add an array property of IAPIError to the IRequest interface.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider that the ApiErrors are going to depend on the particular web service implementation. So how would a client that is using only interfaces going to use the ApiErrors if they are implementation-specific?

It can't - because this would mean that its coupled to this particular implementation.

Instead, you need to abstract away from the specific API error codes, and define your own abstract error codes.

Comment: Obivously but you can use Enums for ErrorType and ErrorNumber and ErrorMessage.  The interface just says hey, you have to provide at the least an array of Errors as a property.  Now the ErrorCode is alos a required property and all APIs will have an error code and that could be an enum defined in each class that implements this property

Comment: ErrorCode is an enum inside ApiError concrete type.  So if I can abstract the ApiError type into an Interface property, at the least, they'd also have to have some sort of Enum called ErrorCode.  Every API is going to have at the least an error code.

Comment: In your example the code is a string, which obvisouly will carry provider-specific error codes. You need some *common* error code which is translated by the provider from the provider-specific error codes.

Comment: Lucero...bare with me.  Ok, yes, but an Api response will ALWAYS give you the error code as a string no matter what provider.

Comment: YOu would define your own abstract error codes in whatever Abstract class you have in x project...that's fine.  But it would have to have an enum called ErrorCode which would be forced by implementing this Interface

Comment: Maybe your API wrapper is thinner than I'd expect it to be. I'd not expose the API internals to the caller more than necessary, and therefore wrap up errors and calls in a interface which only provider the exact functionality your application uses. The app doesn not care if the payment is done via pigeon dollar bill transport or via REST or via SOAP or whatever, it cares about getting the payment done or not and if not why. Therefore I'd abstract all this away from the application to payment interface.

Comment: I think I haven't given enough details. I think you're assuming more than I'm doing.  Anyway thanks a lot for the repsonses

Answer (score 0):

You could put your shared types in a separate, shared assembly: [MyCompany].WebServices.Shared

**Edit**
Come to think of it, you already have that. [MyCompany].WebServices.Common should be as good a place as any for your shared types. Just move it there. Or am I misunderstanding what you want to do?

Comment: then in this case that type would have to be changed into more a generic base class so that I could also extend it then in each wrapper project...I think

Answer (score 0):

The exact error numbers and messages will be very specific for each provider. Therefore, while a common interface can be made, it will not provide enough abstraction to handle errors in a meaningful way.

I'd add another abstraction by defining the expected errors (one of which is "unknown error" as catch-all for unexpected errors) as separate class or even as set of Exceptions. Then, have each provider return or use those, which is already compatible with your application and allows you to handle common errors for all providers the same way.

Put those common types into a separate assembly, which is a pure "interface" assembly used by both the providers and the actual code using them. Therefore you'll be able to loosely couple the providers without having to add references to them in your main application (allowing you to add or modify providers without recompiling the application).

Comment: Error numbers and message types can be handle by Enums that each wrapper project implements themselves.  I can guarantee you that every API is going to have Error numbers.  And every API is going to have a general Error message.  So those are 2 enums that the interface could force also.  What you say is relative to how this is implemented.  It's not totally true what you say here...because there are ways you can make it work.

Comment: The point is that the error codes for "invalid card", "service not available", "aborted" or whatever there is will be different for each provider. Therefore you need to have a common set of errors which are translated by each provider, and which will *not* be the provider's error code. Enums provided in a provider-specific way will not help you here.

Comment: internal ApiError(ErrorType error)
        {
            if(error.ErrorCode != null)
            {
                this._errorCode = error.ErrorCode;
            }

ErrorCode is a enum defined by whatever class implements this Interface.  Why does it matter, all I'm doing is returning it as a property!

Comment: It does matter because the only code able to know what the error actually means in the provider-specific code.

Comment: The constructor of ApiError takes in enum ErrorCode and sets the property ErrorCode.  It's just a class that sets some properties.  That ErrorCode enum could just be a required enum and the class implementing it would have to provide that.  It's just a pass through ..the way I see it.  But it prevents me from having to stub out an ApiError class for every time I want to use it in every project.  Granted the ApiError class wno't have all the properties I need ou said) there are some that will be common such as ErrorCode.  Every Api has an error code associated to an error for the most part

Comment: I'm talking concept, you're talking implementation. So the only thing I can say is that `ApiError` must either be a concrete or abstract class or an interface (all of them work, but which is right depends on your specific design), but it must be defined in the common type assembly I did mention, so that both the app code and the provider code can reference and use it.

Comment: It's a concrete class...gotcha.  I just wanted to know if that's the only alternative, to move that concrete class to the Common project that contains that interface or if there's even anther way to go about this.

Comment: As I said, whether concrete sealed or unsealed, abstract, or an interface - it all comes down to having a common type defined in your "interface assembly". As simple as that.

Comment: The point is not to have common errors that I can play with.  They're all going to have whatever errors that they have.  All I care about is that every wrapper project we create has an array of ApiErrors and the only 2 properties in the ApiError interface is string ErrorCode and string ErrorMessage.  I don't care that they are different but they can all be requierd to implement those properties at the least.

Comment: I'm not looking for commonality across..just a pattern to enforce so at the least I want you to have those 2 properties in your project's Base Response class that implements my IRequest interface and IRequest had an IApiError[] Errors property so that ensures any base classes that implement IRequest will be sure to have an ApiErrors array

Comment: Just do what you think is right for your project, I don't have the knowledge about the details so I can only make assumptions and give hints how I'd solve the problem. In my understanding, an interface (in general, not as "C# interface") should abstract the task at hand and leak as few specific implementation details as necessary. Your design does not do that, it merely wraps and exposes the implementation detail. As I said yesterday, I'm talking concept and you're talking implementation. So if my answer did not help, I'm sorry, but I don't see what else to tell you.